# Is there preformance penalty if I use lambda instead of an If block?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, lambda

I'm using [Dear ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui) to draw my UIs, in immediate mode, in an OpenGL program.

To do a tab, you tipically do:

```cpp
if (ImGui::BeginTabItem("Some Tab")) {
    // Stuff
    ImGui::EndTabItem();
}
```

I come from Kotlin, where you typically use constructs like this:

```kotlin
something("bla bla bla") { x ->
  // whatever
} // this is a Kotlin lambda btw
```

So I wrote a simple wrapper, to wrap the call instead of writing the if and the end call, in order to avoid accidentally omitting the end call:

```cpp
inline void tab(const char* label, std::function<void()> fn)
{
    if (ImGui::BeginTabItem(label)) {
        fn();
        ImGui::EndTabItem();
    }
}
```

Which replaces the first snippet by somehting like:

```cpp
ui::tab("Some other tab", []{
    // More UI...
});
```

The question is, will the compiler emit similar code? Or there will be a big performance impact?

I'm afraid that if the compiler just places a new callable struct each time that the UI is drawn it will be a problem.

*Also*, I'm capturing `this` pointer, to use inside.

```cpp
if (ImGui::BeginTabItem("Some Tab")) {
    // Stuff
    ImGui::EndTabItem();
}

// -- VS -- //

ui::tab("Some other tab", [this]{
    // More UI...
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the "new callable struct each time that the UI is drawn". Classes whose only purpose is clean-up is a common pattern, eg `scoped_lock`, `unqiue_lock` etc, and compilers are rather good at optimizing stuff

Comment: Lambdas don't usually have performance problems; `std::function<void()>` does.

Comment: Profile your code, with all the optimizations enabled.  Profiling is the only way to know.  Without profiling, you are only guessing.

Comment: On what operating system, compiler and platform?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch g++ 9.2.0 (MSYS2), Windows 10

Comment: Compare the outputted assembly?

Comment: @user997112 I'm not really good at reading assembly n.n' but I can give it a try... In this quick bench the assembly seems identical: http://quick-bench.com/k6FBlha1RHT1blwrfY9iTp7aJGM So I suppose that optimization has kicked in.
But if the assembly were too different... I would be clueless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there preformance penalty if I use lambda instead of an If block?

It depends upon your compiler and your [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) flags.

With a modern [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -O3 -mtune=native`, you'll be surprised of the optimizations it is able to do, including [inline expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion). You could be even interested in link time optimization and whole program optimization (e.c. compile *and link* with `gcc -O3 -flto -fwhole-program` ....). Read about GCC [optimization flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC).

See for example [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report, funded by the [CHARIOT](http://www.chariotproject.eu/) H2020 project.

Of course, **the evil is in the details**.

An you could extend GCC with your [plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html#Plugins) improving even more optimizations.

**Be however aware that compiler optimization is *theoretically* undecidable** (see [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), [MRDP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set#Matiyasevich%27s_theorem), [incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems), [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), [AGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence), [J.Pitrat's blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/), the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project, etc...) and practically imperfect (more an art than a science).

The complexity (and trade secrets) of current high-end processors ([CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), [branch predictors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor), [superscalar architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor)) makes [worst-case execution time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_execution_time) analysis practically impossible. In practice, you'll encounter cases where your compiler optimizations will disappoint you. So put efforts on [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) (e.g. with [gprof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprof) or [perf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_(Linux)) on Linux)

See also the [Ctuning](https://ctuning.org/), [CompCert](http://compcert.inria.fr/) and [Milepost GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC) projects. Consider also [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL), [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC).

At last, you could (on many platforms) generate specific code at runtime (using [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) techniques). Consider then using [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries such as [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/). On some operating systems, you could generate C++ code at runtime, then compile it and load it as a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) (e.g. with [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)).

Read of course Thompson [*Reflections on Trusting Trust*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erdriley/487/papers/Thompson_1984_ReflectionsonTrustingTrust.pdf) paper and [Bjarne Stroustrup papers](http://stroustrup.com/papers.html).

You could of course consider using [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) or [LuaJIT](https://luajit.org/). Both can be mixed with C++ on major computing platforms, and practically facilitate runtime code generation so with efforts could improve execution time.

You are coding:

> `inline void tab(const char* label, std::function<void()> fn)`

(and your code don't do what you want if `fn`  is, perhaps indirectly, `throw`-ing some exception) I would suggest instead

```
 inline void tab(const char* label, const std::function<void()>& fn)
```

Comment: Perhaps should be `-mtune=native`

Comment: I see that is a rather difficult subject, I ran a quick bench (I Don't know if the setup is correct): http://quick-bench.com/k6FBlha1RHT1blwrfY9iTp7aJGM
So maybe it can. I'll use lambdas for now and see if becomes a problem in the future.
PS: Thanks for the resources!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't need the full functionality that `std::function` gives you (specifically, its run-time polymorphic behavior), so it's better to not use it.

Just use a template function, this is easier to optimize for a compiler:

```
template <typename CALLABLE>
void tab(const char* label, CALLABLE &&fn)
{
    if (ImGui::BeginTabItem(label)) {
        std::forward<CALLABLE>(fn)();
        ImGui::EndTabItem();
    }
}
```

The only case I'd use `std::function` here, if you wanted to avoid this little code bloat that the template version has, and you wanted to have `tab` as a non-inlined function.

The reason is that `std::function` may be a worse solution is that `std::function` needs to store the lambda (and its captured variables) somewhere. The heap is usually used for this (except if it fits in `std::function`'s small-object optimization space - but now you're relying on that an implementation `std::function`'s does have this small-object space, and the compiler is able to optimize around this). So it's easier to just the template version, compilers are very good around optimizing this, as the standard library uses this technique very heavily.

Comment: Thanks for the template hint! I've switched to a template const ref to avoid copying whatever I'm passing.

Comment: @SigmaSoldier: My example uses forwarding reference, it won't copy either.

Comment: True! I can use that also